# javascript function doesn't seem to be calling

Tags: javascript, ajax, search, dynamic

I am creating an AJAX dynamic search bar which returns results from a database. I find that when i open the debugger, the code isn't entering the function ***handleSuggest()*** which sets the inner html of the div where the results are shown. Here is my code.

```
function getXmlHttpRequestObject(){
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject){
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
else{
    alert("Your browser does not support our dynamic search");
}
}

var search = getXmlHttpRequestObject();

function ajaxSearch(){
if (search.readyState == 4 || search.readyState == 0){
    var str = escape(document.getElementById('searchBox').value);
    search.open("GET", 'searchSuggest.php?search=' + str, true);
    search.onreadystatechange.handleSearchSuggest();
    search.send(null);
}
}

function handleSearchSuggest(){
    if(search.readyState == 4){
        var ss = document.getElementById('ajaxSearch');
        ss.innerHTML = '';
        var str = search.responseText.split("\n");
        for(i=0; i<str.length-1; i++){
            var suggestion = '<div onmouseover="javascript:suggestOver(this);"';
            suggestion += 'onmouseout="javascript.suggestOut(this);"';
            suggestion += 'onclick="javascript:setSearch(this.innerHTML);"';
            suggestion += 'class="suggestLink">' + str[i] + '<div>';
            ss.innerHTML += suggestion;
        }
    }
}

function suggestOver(divValue){
    divValue.className = "suggestLink";
}

function suggestOut(divValue){
    divValue.className = "suggestLink";
}

function setSearch(x){
    document.getElementById('searchBox').value = x;
    document.getElementById('ajaxSearch').innerHTML = '';
}
```

Comment: This question is very specific: try reducing your code to the smallest example of the problem. Better yet, include a jsfiddle with the example.

Comment: inside your function ajaxSearch you should do this `search.onreadystatechange = handleSearchSuggest;` take a [look](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
search.onreadystatechange.handleSearchSuggest();
```

`search.onreadystatechange` needs a callback function assigned to it.

Change it to the following:

```
search.onreadystatechange = handleSearchSuggest;
```

Note that this does not invoke the `handleSearchSuggest` function here as `onreadystatechange` needs a callback function not the result of the function.

Comment: How should i go about adding a callback function?

Comment: `handleSearchSuggest` is your callback function.

Comment: The console is now giving me this error:
TypeError: search.onreadystatechange is null

Comment: Do you have your `search.send(null);` statement after you set `search.onreadystatechange`?

Comment: Try setting `search.onreadystatechange = function() { console.log (search.responseText) }` for debugging.